# In custom observer Data not updated or inserted in custom table but last insert id show and no error coming

Tags: event-observer

I created custom observer and on event i called function. but nothing is add in database or updated nothing. But show successful insertion and also give me last insert id.

`config.xml`:-

```
   <events>
        <sales_order_place_before>
            <observers>
                <ip_prohibited_model_onepage>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Ip_Prohibited_Model_Onepage</class>
                    <method>gardnerBookOrderPlace</method>
                </ip_prohibited_model_onepage>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_before>
    </events>
```

`onepage.php` :- (In Model)

```
$model = Mage::getModel('prohibited/prohibited');
$model->setUserid('123');
$model->save();
//Mage::log($model, null, "order.log", true);
try {
    $insertId = $model->save()->getId();
    //echo "Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: ".$insertId;
    Mage::log("Data successfully inserted. Insert ID: ".$insertId, null, "order.log", true);
} catch (Exception $e){
    //echo $e->getMessage(); 
    Mage::log($e->getMessage(), null, "order.log", true);
}
```

Can anyone can help me to sort out this issue.

Comment: flush your magento cache

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in your custom table there is a column called `user_id`.
In this case you need to change the line `$model->setUserid('123');` to `$model->setUserId('123');` (notice the capital I).
Also, as a bonus, you don't need to call `save` twice on your model. It's just a waste of resources.  Remove `$model->save();` that you added outside the `try` section.